# How to package dependencies into java project with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies, snakeyaml

I get this error when I try to run my project.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/yaml/snakeyaml/Yaml

I am trying to include the dependency SnakeYaml.jar in my project so my project is only one jar instead of requiring an external dependency.

in my project SnakeYaml.jar is located at /Libs/SnakeYaml.jar

but it is not being loaded at runtime, what can I do to get it to load the resource at runtime?

Comment: tried adding the jar in classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution to avoid such problems is creating maven based project by eclipse. when you export your project as `jar` or `war` files it puts all dependencies in the jar or war files

[image]

Comment: but does it load the classes from the dependency at runtime? or is there something else I must do?

Comment: I tried converting my project from a java project to a maven project but I still get the 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/yaml/snakeyaml/Yaml

Comment: Have you added the dependencies in the Pom.xml ?

Comment: yes it is in the pom, and I changed it from compile to runtime and made it managed. when I look in the jar file that was exported it does not contain the dependency. please explain the process of adding the dependency and exporting it from eclipse.
http://pastebin.com/vvCTLn84

Comment: Did you create a new project or you converted the old one to maven based project? I recommend you create a new project and add your java files to that.

Comment: do i do buildpath libraries "add external jar" or maven "add dependency"?

Comment: I created a new project, added my source code, I added the repository and the dependency to the pom.xml, changed the dependency to runtime instead of compile, exported as a jar with "Export generated class files and resources" and I still get "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/yaml/snakeyaml/Yaml"

Comment: I think my problem is I'm not using maven to build the project, so I tried run-as maven build and set the goals as compile and these are the errors it gave me
http://pastebin.com/rHLGugh3

Comment: I added the maven-compiler and maven-jar plugins and now it says build success but still does not have the dependencies in it

Comment: finally, after installing the shade plugin, doing mvn package created the shaded jar with dependencies

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, to put the dependency packaged inside your project executable jar you can do this:

I cannot post images due to my reputation so will try to explaing it writting.

- Make sure the dependency is in your class path: right click the project -> Build Path
- Right click your project again and select "Export"
- Now choose "Runnable JAR file" (you can filter the list by typing)
- In the next dialog choose the right option for you, in your case it could be "Package required libraries into generated JAR"

Hope it helps

Comment: The "Export" option isn't necessary here. Only the final step is required.

Comment: I attempted this but still had the same problem, it doesn't load the classes from the dependency at runtime so I get the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: Right click your project, go to Build Path -> Configure Build Path and then make sure the library jar is under the library tab.

Comment: my project does not have a Main function. It is used by another project